# Taking text from selenium web object and appending it to a list line by line

Tags: python, selenium

I see so many tutorials out there that take a document and append it to a python list line by line. I have selenium grabbing text from a web object and storing it in variable working_proxies.

Is there anyway to take the text and turn it into a list without having to download then reopen a file?

The text looks like this:

0.0.0.0:0000

1.11.111.1:1

222.2.12.89:10

and so on...

```
                if (int(percentage) == 100):
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="e_popup"]').click()
                    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
                    time.sleep(2)
                    working_proxies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/pre').text
                    driver.close()
                    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
                    break
                else:
                    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: So, you want to take the proxy and not to put in a file , but you want to do what? I kinda got loat there

Comment: its a list of proxies and i want them saved to a list instead of a file on the computer.

Comment: Make a forloop and append everyone of them in a list ? And then use that list ??

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question - this sample neither saves to a file, nor tries to see something to a list. All it does is getting the text of some element `'/html/body/pre'`; which without context (an example of the HTML source) is also not sufficient for us to help you.

Comment: Does the string you get back from `.text` have all the text? If so, then you just have to convert that string to an array using methods like `.split()`